# How to configure swagger in netcore2.1 with an area?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, area

I am using dotnet core 2.1 to build a Restful API for my apps. I want to use
swagger to visualize my webapi, but when we use [an area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it fails. Is there somebody who can tell me how to config swagger with an area? tks so much!

Comment: What do you mean when you write. "configure swagger with an area?" For instance, do you mean that your API controllers are in an area? Do you mean that swagger is in an area? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Can you share your configuration code, project structure and error you got please ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Take a minute and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with more details what exactly isn't working, what you are trying and what you did try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the controller with route attribute

```
[Route("AREA/CONTROLLER")]
```

In Startup.cs

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.

app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MovieRank V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```